# PHP can't connect to 127.0.0.1 or localhost to galera but can iva mysql cmd

Tags: php, galera

I am having an issue with MySQL where I can't connect via localhost or 127.0.0.1, I get "Access denied ". On the same box if I use

```
mysql -p -h localhost -u mysuser -p'mypassword'
```

or

```
mysql -p -h 127.0.0.1 -u mysuser -p'mypassword'
```

I am able to get in with no issue. I checked the MySQL users table and I have an entry for user mysql with host %, localhost and 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

ID10T error. I had a bad password....